# Divide and be conquered

Tags: passive-voice, rhetoric

Sometimes, when you divide something into many pieces, the many pieces overwhelm you, like what happened to Mickey Mouse in [*Fantasia*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DX2yVucz24). This suggests a variation on *divide et vinces*:

> Divide et vincere.

But does this have the clarity or punch of English "Divide and be conquered"? I'm wondering because *vincere* is the infinitive as well as the 2nd-person passive—which could be *vincĕre* or *vincēre* for present or future, possibly further blurring the meaning in a terse phrase. Is there a better way to put this thought in Latin?

Comment: What about a subjunctive?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Can you illustrate? I wouldn't want to say "May you divide and be conquered" (at least not unintentionally). :)

Comment: "Mickey Mouse in Fantasia" > "the sorcerer's apprentice in Goethe".

Comment: *Divide et vincaris*, "Divide and may you be conquered," which really expands to, "If you divide, you may be conquered."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your phrase *Dīvide et vincēs*, the second verb is future rather than imperative, so if you're OK with that phrasing you could do the same here to avoid the ambiguity of form: *Dīvide et vincēris*.

For "Divide and rule" Wiki [gives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_rule) the Latin versions *Dīvide et imperā* and *Dīvide ut regnēs*. Passivizing the first (*Dīvide et imperāre*) doesn't avoid the ambiguity, and a purpose clause seems unsuitable in this case. But you might consider a conditional: *Sī dīvidēs, vincēris*.

Comment: Of course—*vinceris*! Thanks. I haven't touched Latin in a couple months and looked at [a grammar table](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vinco#Inflection), and _vincere_ caught my eye first. Wow, I'd even forgotten that after reading questions like [this](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/781/118) and [this](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/483/118) I had resolved to just avoid those alternate _-ere_ forms!